# Increase Spring data ingest speed

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

We have an IOT app that receives data on kafka and processes it saves in rdbms. The db that we are using(MemSql) supports more than 20000 inserts per second. But with my regular repository.save method I have been able to achieve only 50 inserts per sec. I have made a simple code that I am testing on a high network speed aws ec2 instance

```
void saveA(){
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
       A obj = new A();
       aRepository.save(obj);
    }
}
```

This takes 20 seconds to complete. I wish to achieve around 1000k inserts per sec. How do increase this ingestion speed? Should I create a create a thread pool of size 1000 and call save from separate thread? In that case case do I need to care about properties like spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active to increase number of connections in the pool? Would spring data automatically pick a separate connection from pool for each thread?
I can't do batch inserts as I am reading data from kafka one at a time and also because there could be some duplicate data that I need to catch as DataIntegrityViolationException and update.

Answer (score 1):

You don't describe how complex the objects are that you are saving, but it sounds like you have fairly simple objects, i.e. the ration of inserts per save operation is close to 1 and you also don't seem to do many updates, if at all.

If that is the case I'd recommend ditching JPA and going straight for JDBC (using the `JdbcTemplate`)

The reason is that JPA does a lot of thing for making the typical JPA process work: Load an entity graph, manipulate it, and flush it back to the database.
But you don't do that and so JPA might not help much and makes your life hard because you need to tune JPA and JDBC.

Start with performing the inserts directly using `JdbcTemplate`.

The next step would be to perform batch inserts.
You write you can't do that but I don't see why you can't collect a couple of rows before writing them to the database.

Comment: Another reason I can't do batch updates is because there could be some duplicate data that I need to catch as DataIntegrityViolationException and update. What do you think about using thread pool based approach?

Comment: If you don't know that CPU is your bottleneck, going for a threads is quackery in my opinion.

Comment: You can do batches in the presence of constraint violations. You might want to look into Spring Data Batch for some help in doing these non trivial exception handlings.

Comment: The database I am using (MemSql) does not allow sequence type generated id so I am using IDENTITY for @GeneratedValue. Since spring data does not allow batch updates for identity, is there any other way to generate primary ids? Or should I use string Uuid as primary key?